# Proper backslash definition in a -string (macOS defaults write via shell)

Tags: macos, shell, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to set up a macOS keyboard shortcut (`ctrl+shift+up_arrow`) from the terminal.

After creating it manually from System Preferences I found out that `'^$\\U2191'` is the string I'm looking for.

So:

```
defaults write com.hello.app NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add 'Test' -string '^$\\U2191'
```

However, this is what I get by running `defaults read com.hello.app NSUserKeyEquivalents`:

```
{"Test" = "^$\\\\\\\\U2191";}
```

Why every backslash is being duplicated twice? How to properly input **only** two backslashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that, when it comes to special characters, the only way to edit the `plist` file from the cli is to include the special characters themselves.

```
defaults write com.hello.app NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add 'Test' -string '^$↓'
```

I don't know how other keys are dealt with, but [PLIST Editor](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/plist-editor/id1157491961?mt=12) is a good way to quickly grab those values after manually creating the shortcut the first time.

Answer (score 1):

To add to [Luke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59317454/3595355), I figured out how you can set a hotkey involving a key like <kbd>F4</kbd>:

1. Go to **System Settings** → **Keyboard** → **Keyboard Shortcuts...** → **App Shortcuts**.
2. Manually add your shortcut (e.g. <kbd>⌥⌘F4</kbd>). Note: this is only so that you can get the Unicode code point of the key that you press; once you have it, you'll be able to automate this.
3. Read the shortcut that you just set.

   1. Find the name of the app with `defaults domains`. E.g. I added my shortcut to Chrome, so the domain I need to use is `com.google.Chrome`.
   2. Run `defaults read com.google.Chrome NSUserKeyEquivalents`

You should get output like this (where "Whatever Shortcut You Set" will be a menu command like "New Tab"):

```
{
    "Whatever Shortcut You Set" = "@~\\Uf707";
}
```

4. Run `zsh` with the following command: `echo \\Uf707 | pbcopy` (note that `bash` would likely require different syntax). Your clipboard should now contain the special character representing <kbd>F4</kbd>.
5. Run `defaults write com.google.Chrome NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Whatever Shortcut You Set" -string '@~X'`

Note: the `X` above is not really an "X"; it's the character that should now be on your clipboard from step #4. For me, iTerm 2 rendered it like an eyeball, but that's because `U+F707` has no corresponding renderable character.

6. Restart the app whose shortcut you just set. You should now have <kbd>⌥⌘F4</kbd> set as a shortcut!

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes (") instead of single ones (') for the `-string` parameters:

`defaults write com.hello.app NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add 'Test' -string "^$\\U2191"`

Comment: Have you personally tried this? It's not working for me, the single/double quotes do not change anything.

Comment: Yes. With single quotes, when you do `defaults read com.hello.app NSUserKeyEquivalents` you get `{Test = "^$\\\\\\\\U2191";}`. When you insert with the double quotes, the results is: `{Test = "^$\\\\U2191";}`

Answer (score -1):

In most Posix-based languages, including those used on MacOS, backslash is a reserved character.

For the parser to print a backslash you need to input backslash twice.

Some scripts and utilities will presume you want literal printing and insert double backslash in place of backslash in order to give literal printing, instead of looking for the characters.

You need to check the documentation of the particular tool.  There is often an option to turn off this feature.

Comment: Thanks bro, very helpful... They guy was asking **how** to disable this behavior for the `defaults` tool...